# Removing/Adding JComponents depending on if boolean equals to true or false

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton, actionlistener

In a game that I am currently making I have just created a starting screen. That starting screen have 4 `JButton`s Play, Options, Credit and Quit. If you press Play another JButton will appear, New Game.

I wan't to make it so that when you press the New Game button the starting screen disapears and the game start (both the acctual game and the staring screen extends `JComponent`).

I have a seperate class that runs the game and handels the in-game option menu.

In the starting screen class I have a `boolean` called startGame, that boolean equals to false by default and when you press the New Game button it will equal to true. In the starting menu class I also have a public method that returns the value of startGame, it looks like this.

```
public boolean checkGame(){
    return startGame;
}
```

In the main class that runs the game I check if the checkGame method equals to true or false by using a Timer like this.

```
if(menu.checkGame() == false){
            frame.add(menu);
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(menu.checkGame() == true){
                    frame.remove(menu);
                    frame.add(new Level1());
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
```

Obviously this does not work because if it would I would not be asking this question. So now to my question, how would I make it work like I want?

Comment: Why not have all the components running, but have their visibility hidden until called.

Comment: The `ActionListener` you have in the `Timer`, why not make that the `ActionListener` of the startGame button?

Comment: @kuporific because it will be more convenient later on if I do it this way

Comment: @Tdorno Wouldn't that make the game run slower?

Comment: @MysticKiller98 I would but you wouldn't notice it

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are you assuming the `Timer` runs once or repeatedly? You might try using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to repeatedly call `menu.checkGame()`, just remember to remove the scheduled task.

Answer (score 0):

In your second code snippet, the `Timer` only runs its task once. Perhaps you want a `ScheduledExecutorService` to repeatedly check, for example:

```
    final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (menu.checkGame()) {
                        frame.remove(menu);
                        frame.add(new Level1());
                        scheduledExecutor.shutdown();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```